# X-Cache: Error from cloudfront / 500 internal error AWS AMPLIFY

Tags: amazon-web-services, npm, next.js, amazon-cloudfront, aws-amplify

I deployed a nextjs app on netlify, had a successful build but i kept on getting a 500 internal error after some digging with burp suite, I came upon this response "X-Cache: Error from cloudfront"

[image]

I did some further deep dive using cloudwatch and stumbled on this!

[image]

So my question here is:

1. Is this a code issue
2. Is this an amplify error
3. Is this a configuration error

please not the error is coming from requesting the root path i.e "/"